# Products are not displaying in Frontend after import in Magento

Tags: magento, import

I have imported products using System - Import/Export - Import option.

I can see my products in Admin panel, but not in Frontend.

I tried Re-indexing, cache clear, cache refresh, physical cache remove.

also checked product stock status, availability etc. Everything is ok.

But they are not displaying in frontend. I marked onething, If I open product that I imported using csv, just saved without any change, it starts displaying. But I have 100s of products. So I can't use this solution.

So please help me where I am going wrong in csv. below is my csv screenshot.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check the website tab ? and also they assigned to category or not.

Comment: What change do I need to do in my csv file?

Comment: First check find the issue after that change csv.try on one or two products these tests .

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the products are attached to a website.

This can be done via a bulk update:

- Access the product listm select all
- Alter attribute
- Products information -> websites

It can also be done in the csv by using a "_product_websites" field and setting it to the website name or 'base'.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot which CSV columns are mandatory but I do remember that if some are missing the importer does not tell you that but instead you get the behaviour that you are describing.

The simplest way to find out what is mandatory is to:

1. **Fix bugs in Magento ImportExport module**
2. Create a new product in admin
3. Check that the new product is visible on front-end
4. Export the new product with Magento ImportExport exporter
5. Delete created product
6. Import the previously exported product csv
7. Clear cache and reindex data
8. Check that product is visible on front-end (it should be)
9. Compare your CSV with the exported one and try to figure out what is missing from it
10. Try to import your CSV with added/fixed columns and add data untill the product is imported so that it is visible on front-end

This requires allot of trial and error...

The missing columns in my case had always the same value so if this will be the case with your problem as well you can simply extend CSV importer and hard code those values in there instead of fixing your CSV manually.

Since your product gets saved correctly if you open it in admin and save it you can also:

1. Import a product
2. Export that product
3. Open that product in admin and save it
4. Export newly saved product
5. Compare exported CSV-s where they differ

**Fixing Magento ImportExport bugs:**

First bug is that if you import multiple products the quantity informatino from the first product is used for all the products. To fix this you have to add `$row = array();` right before `$row['product_id'] = $this->_newSku[$rowData[self::COL_SKU]]['entity_id'];` in `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Product::_saveStockItem()` function.

The second bug causes Magento ImportExport module to return a foreign key constraint error when importing multiple products. Error happens because magento splits products data into multiple segments and if one product is located in two segments importer will delete data that was imported for the product in first segment before importing the second segment thereby causing database corruption (see [this link](http://twistersfury.com/foregin-key-constraint-errors-on-magento-import/#.UZE4BdfKW_Q) for detailed explanation - this is where I got the solution below).

Note that removing foreign key constraint will not fix the problem but will instead make it worse since the database will contain corrupt data.

To fix it you have to change the code in `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Abstract::_saveValidatedBunches()` function:

After `if ($startNewBunch || !$source->valid()) {` add

```
if ($startNewBunch && count($bunchRows) > 1) {
  $arrKeys = array_keys($bunchRows);
  $arrNew  = array();
  while(($tRow = array_pop($bunchRows))) {
    $tKey = array_pop($arrKeys);

    $arrNew[$tKey] = $tRow;

    if ($tRow['sku']) {
      break;
    }
  }
  $nextRowBackup = array_reverse($arrNew, TRUE) + $nextRowBackup;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently and I spent some time tring to figure it out...

Looks like magento needs a status flag for every product otherwise magento will not show it   in the dashboard.

Solution : add a "status" column to your CSV file and set all the statuses to "Enabled" 
(yes it's not a boolean. Just use the string inside the quotes as it is :)

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem, i then visited my var/export/export_all_products file, downloaded it again and uploaded the same back through import, logged out of my account and logged-in back, all products were back. This worked as a backup for me and i could see all the products back at the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import as you have. If they are enabled, but not showing...
2. then you can fix this by clicking "select all" products in the "manage products" table and then "change status" and then select "enabled." This process might take a minute.
3. Visit your store and you should see your frontend with products.

Some kind of bug with the status/enabled setting.

Answer (score 0):

You must have next fields in CSV

```
sku 
_attribute_set 
_type 
_category 
description 
image 
name 
price 
short_description 
status 
tax_class_id 
thumbnail 
visibility 
weight 
qty 
_product_websites 
is_in_stock
```

Please note that field `is_in_stock` is mandatory even if `qty` more then 1

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 we need to reindex in index management to display the products in frontend.
We can reindex through cmd.like the given example we need to enter magento file directory after that cmd `php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex` to reindex .

[image: 1]

Answer (score -1):

When I first started importing products via csv although I set the product to enabled, I figured out that even though it shows in the magento back end as enabled, it actually isnt - think its to do with setting the field contents as "1" or "0" rather than "enabled" or "disabled/null".

To get around this, after a import I simply selected all the products in the back end and change status to enabled - it fixes issue.

But, I do think if I simply changed the data in the csv import it would save me this minor in-convenience.